# Accessing member function with pointer vs object

Tags: c++

Hello I started learning c++ and I'm following a video tutorial series.

For the sake of simplicity consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
public:
    Test();
    void printCrap();
private:
protected:
};

Test::Test(){

};

void Test::printCrap(){
    cout << "I don't get this yet..." << endl;
};

int main(){

    Test testOne;
    Test *testTwo = &testOne;

    testOne.printCrap();
    testTwo->printCrap();

    return 0;
};
```

It's similar to the tutorial's code with the only exception that I merged the code into 1 cpp for the sake of this question.

What the tutorial doesn't explain is beside the obvious what are is the actual difference / benefits and where is this applicable.Perhaps a scenario where `->` vs `.` would matter?

Comment: The only difference is that `testTwo` may contain an invalid address (in the general case, not in your example)

Comment: [This example is an answer](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/an-example-of-c-dot-and-arrow-usage/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, use `.` when the variable you're calling through is either an actual object or a reference.  Use `->` when the variable is a pointer-to-object.

In general, prefer to use either actual objects or reference-to-objects.  Pointers are used on as as-needed basis.  Some cases where you often need to use pointers are:

1. In using polymorphism
2. When you need the object to outlive the scope in which it was created

Comment: Thank you for mentioning 1 , 2.

Comment: References are fine for polymorphism as well.

Answer (score 3):

`testTwo->printCrap()` is just syntactic sugar for `(*testTwo).printCrap()`, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Assuming that `testTwo` is a pointer, not a class (with defined operator `*` and/or `->`).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of benefits or differences. If you have a pointer you need to dereference it to access members. The `->` operator is equivalent to

```
testTwo->print();
(*testTwo).print();  // same thing.
```

If you have an instance (or reference) you use

```
testTwo.print();
```

This is the language syntax - its not about preferences

Answer (score 1):

Its just a memory work. When you allocate it

```
Test testOne;
```

you just create an object in memory with you operate, when you point at it

```
Text *testTwo = &testOne;
```

you point at same location whenre testOne is.
You just created another name for the same part of memory.
And when you need to pass this thing to a function, you don't want to create whole new object, but you just want to point at it like

```
function workWithObject(Test *testit)
```

So the testit points to same part of memory as testTwo and it is textOne.

Comment: Hmm I see that clarified some things for me, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The . (dot) operator and the -> (arrow) operator are used to reference individual members of classes, structures, and unions.

The dot operator is applied to the actual object. The arrow operator is used with a pointer to an object.

```
Test testOne;
Test* testTwo = &testOne;
```

here testTwo is a pointer variable of type Test pointing at memory location of testOne, to access the members of Test class with testTwo it needs to dereference which is done with the help of -> arrow operator.

Answer (score 0):

Well member of class can be accessed by applying `.` operator to an object of class testTwo or by applying the `->` to a pointer of class testTwo. Arrow `->` came from C time and abit redundant.

Also inside class you don't need any operators. Just call printCrap. And if you looking for in static member function you use :: f.e. `testOne::staticPrint.`

Answer (score 0):

imaging you have another class, Test2, which is inherited from your original Test. Test2 has is own version of printCrap() function. We have two ways calling:

```
//as member function
Test.printCrap();
Test2.printCrap();
//as pointer 
ptr = &Test;
ptr->printCrap();
ptr = &Test2;
ptr->printCrap();
```

The above code illustrate the usage only, doesn't tell which one is better.